# Is there a way to know what version of each gradle dependency I had on a certain build?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Recently I had a crash popup with MoPub all of the sudden between two releases in which I didn't touch MoPub. Turns out their suggested configuration for gradle is `com.mopub:mopub-sdk:+@aar` and it had updated without me noticing. It took me a while to notice that MoPub had updated.

If I could commit some file that has all the versions of gradle dependencies the app used then I could more easily compare between builds.

Is there a file that has all that information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate a resolved dependency report and save it:

`./gradlew dependencies`

Or you could use [dependency locking](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_locking.html) and check this in to your SCM so that you can rebuild an older version with the exact dependencies used at release time.

You add this to your build.gradle

```
dependencyLocking {
    lockAllConfigurations()
}
```

Then you generate the lock files using `./gradlew dependencies --write-locks` and check those in to your source control.  If the lock file is present, then those versions override anything in the build.gradle.  You can update the locked version on future releases by passing the `--write-locks` option and committing the changes back to your SCM.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds exactly like what I want. I will probably lean towards the first option but the second one sounds very interesting, if I use locking, do I have to remove the locks manually each time I want to upgrade some library?

Comment: @casolorz No, you do not have to remove the file.  If the file is present and you run a build, gradle will use the version from the lock file.  If you want to upgrade all your dynamic dependencies, you can just reissue the `--write-locks` and then submit the changed lock files back to your SCM